# php htmlentities to decode textarea

Tags: php, textarea, html-entities, html-encode

I have a text area and I would like to take the input of the text area and merge it all together. Everything works fine except that it's escaping the quotes. For example `test's` is outputted as `test/'s`

To fix this I tried htmlenttries such as,

```
<?php $inputtext= $_POST['textinput'];
        $encodetext = htmlentities($inputtext);
        $finaltext = html_entity_decode($encodetext);

        echo '<p>'.$finaltext .'</p>';  ?>
```

This should work according to the [html_entity_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) manual (unless I read it wrong which could very likely be the case)

Comment: Do you get "test/'s" or "test\'s"? Also, the code you posted doesn't print escaped quotes.

Comment: Do you have magic quotes enabled by any chance?

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by calling `htmlentities` followed by `html_entity_decode`? They are the inverses of each other, so `html_entity_decode(htmlentities($str)) == $str`.

Comment: Jan raises a very good point. Dump the original data as well as the processed data to make sure the original is as you expect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is probably for you to strip slashes.

The slashes are automatically added when data comes from POST or GET. This is known as magic quotes and by default are enabled.

You can remove these slashes by using `stripslashes()`

```
<?php

$text = $_POST['txtarea']; // from textarea
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
  $text = stripslashes($text);
  // strip off the slashes if they are magically added.
}
$text = htmlentities($text);
// what htmlentities here does is really to convert:
//   & to &amp;
//   " to &#039;
//  and change all < and > to &lt; and &gt; respectively. this will automatically disable html codes in the text.
echo '<pre>'.$text.'</pre>';

?>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php

Comment: **NB:**, `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` _always returns FALSE as of PHP 5.4.0_ [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php#refsect1-function.get-magic-quotes-gpc-changelog), so the code should read now `if ( get_magic_quotes_gpc() || version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.4.0', '>') ) {`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$encodetext = htmlentities ($inputtext, ENT_QUOTES);` which will not try to escape the single and double quotes. Look under *flags* here: [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you aren't passing second parameters in your calls to `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`. If you do, they will escape/unescape quotes differently. Check the description of the `$quote_style` parameter in the documentation for [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) and [`html_entity_decode`](http://php.net/html_entity_decode).