# Convert WYSIWYG's outputted HTML with slashes & quotes

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg

I have a WYSIWYG editor (TinyMCE) to add blog articles to my website. If I just write a fairly normal paragraph:

```
<p><strong>Hello world!</strong></p>
```

It outputs just fine. But if I try some extra HTML, for example links and underlines, my editor kicks out the following, which when printed to screen doesn't work or doesn't look right:

```
<p>This is some test <span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\">content</span> with <a href=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;http:/www.google.com\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\" target=\"\\&quot;\\\\&quot;_blank\\\\&quot;\\&quot;\">more</a> <em>tags</em> than I would <strong>normally</strong> add.</p>
```

This is a mess of slashes and quotes. How am I supposed to sort this out? Which methods or functions? I'm more concerned about the links than the style tags. Any advice would be great.

**UPDATE 1**
I've since used **stripslashes()** which fixed the `<SPAN>` tag but didn't fix the `A` tag.

**MY SETUP**
This is my TinyMCE editor code:

```
<script>
tinyMCE.init({
    mode : "exact",
    elements : "content",
    theme : "advanced",
    plugins : "autolink,lists,spellchecker,pagebreak,advhr,advlink,iespell,inlinepopups,"
    + "print,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras",
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,bullist,"
    + "numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
    width: "100%",
    height: "425"
});
</script>
```

The textareas content is then posted (POST) to another page via AJAX and then stored *as-is* to the database. When I go and print this WYSIWYG HTML to the page, from my DB, I write:

```
<?php
echo stripslashes($dbResults['article_body']);
?>
```

Comment: have a read on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960920/php-htmlentities-to-decode-textarea

Comment: @Deepak: Thanks, that sorted the `SPAN` tag but not the `<A>` tag.

Comment: what is the actual link you are trying to do ? can you post the actual  data you are using on TinyMCE and the code you are using now to get your `span` tag right ?

Comment: Are you using the tinymce HTML editor or just pasting this right into the text field?

Comment: @Deepak: I have updated my question for you which explains a bit more.

Comment: @jchapa: I'm not pasting, no. I'm using the TinyMCE editor to write this. To get the <A> link, I click TinyMCE's link button, insert a URL and it automatically adds the HTML in the background.

Comment: What happens when you remove the "autolink" option from the plugins?

Comment: @inhan: That worked. Write that as an answer please and I'll accept it. Not sure why I have the autolink plugin, I'll need to read about that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "autolink" plugin apparently changes possible links by itself so that's why it's getting changed twice, by you and the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

What about the following block ?

```
<?php
  echo html_entity_decode(stripslashes($dbResults['article_body']));
?>
```

Comment: Somebody in my question's comments just pinpointed the problem. Thanks a lot for your help my friend.